# Is it possible to use irrefutable tilde (`~`) patterns in lambda expressions?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

GHC gives me a `parse error on input \~` if I try to put a tilde on the pattern of a lambda expression like I can do with named functions

```
let step = \~(x,s) -> run (f x) s  -- Parse Error

let step ~(x, s) = run (f x) s -- Works fine
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to add a space between the lambda and the tilde

```
\ ~(x,s) -> run (f x) s
```

The source of the confusion is because `\` and `~` are both valid characters for user defined operators so `\~` is parsed as one instead of being parsed as the start of a lambda expression:

```
-- Defining a custom \~ operator is allowed:
let a \~ b = {- ... -}
```

Comment: After wasting much more time then I would like on this one, I acidentaly found the solution while writing down the original version of this question. I guess still posting it might help someone though...

Comment: You should add the explanation, though. Both ``\`` and `~` are symbols and can appear in operators, so `\~` is lexed as one token.